# Why is ng-submit not calling $scope function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, angularjs

I have this  :

```
<div id="StopDialog" title="Stop Service">
    <form ng-submit="stopService()">
        <p>Why do you want to stop this service?</p>
        <input type="text" ng-model="stopReason" />
        <input type="submit" value="Stop" />
    </form>
</div>
```

The form in the html should call this function:

```
$scope.stopService = function () {
        $("#dvProccessing").center();
        $("#dvProccessing").show();
        console.log($scope.stopReason);
        $http({
            type: "POST",
            url: "StopService?ServiceName=" + clickedService[1] + "&ServerName=" + clickedService[2] + "&Reason=" + $scope.stopReason,
            success: function (result) {
                $("#dvProccessing").hide();
                if (!result.IsSuccess) {
                    alert(result.Message);
                }
            },
            error: function () { $("#dvProccessing").hide(); }
        });
   };
```

I know that the ng-submit directive is not calling the stopService function because the console log does not show the $scope.reason model that the user entered with the form and the processing div that is supposed to be shown when the function runs is also not appearing.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have defined `ng-app` && `ng-controller`?

Comment: Not sure `.center()` exists in jQuery. Is it declared elsewhere ?

Comment: @Satpal wow that was totally stupid, ng-app and controller are declared but these divs belong outside of it's scope, thank you

Comment: As a side note, you shouldn't mix Angular and jQuery inside a controller (I assume it's a controller). You can easily show/hide things by using `ng-show` and `ng-hide`.

Comment: @MichaelBenford Thanks for the advice, I am actually just updating this code to include angular, but because all of this was previously written in jquery i kept some of the stuff so that this view's controller wouldnt have to be changed extensively